# Why web elements lie in just one element of a list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, selenium, xpath, append

I crawled data from Scopus website and saved it in the list named "s". But all of the data have been saved in s[1]. My code is:

```
s=[]
document=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="srchResultsList"]/tbody""")
for i in document:
    s.append(i.text)
```

What should I do? I used selenium package in python 2.7.

Comment: if you need to get table data you need to iterate through `tr` (rows) and `td` (columns) not the `tbody`

Comment: Post a link to the page and explain more about what exactly you are looking for. Give an example of the relevant HTML, what you expect to get from the HTML, and the code you are using to get that HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are trying to query a `tbody` table tag. It it not the reason? Generally there is only a tbody tag inside a table, and it results in a unique element.

You didn't told us if you are trying to return and save in your var all tr elements, or all td elements, or even another kind of tag inside of they, but whatever you are trying to return, you need to change your selector.

Let's imagine that your xpath returns a tbody element with a ton of IWebElements inside of it: tr, td, a, span... But **your selector is asking only for the tbody element, not the inside elements**, do you get it?

just try to change your xpath to `//*[@id="srchResultsList"]/tbody/tr` if you want all tr elements exept headers tr;

You can also use the following xpath `//*[@id="srchResultsList"]/tbody//td` that will return all td elements that you want.

In another case, if you want all tr AND td elements inside tbody, you can query that way: 
`//*[@id="srchResultsList"]/tbody/tr | //*[@id="srchResultsList"]/tbody//td`

You can also change or create subqueryes to return all elements what you desire for, but you need to specify it on selector: **selenium just accepts the imediate result without children**

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. Your response is well. But has a mistake in indexing of the list. I must have a list of 200 roes, but, the list has 202 rows. What is your opinion about this?

Comment: I just need to understand what you want: The returned value inside selenium is wrong? Or you want to take a specified quantity of elements?

Comment: Anyways, you can always use the chrome console window to test all yours xpath and cssSelectors:  try to use `$("your-css-selector")` or `$x("your-xpath")`. I dont know if another browsers support the xpath selector since it is a console feature, not js or jquery. But chrome surely supports